# How to Index My Desktop

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, windows-explorer, filesystems, search-indexing

I keep a bunch of files on my dekstop...word files and writings I'm working on at the time.

I would like to be able to search for a specific file that has some word written inside it...however, for some reason, I can't seem to index my desktop.

Only my drive appears...

[image]

Thanks!

---

I know that Users, which is under My Drive, deep down includes a file called Desktop...but that file is empty:

[image]

Unlike my other Desktop, which is full of stuff:

[image]

---

Found the problem...look at the top answer. However, that isn't enough...for some reason, some files still don't show when I search from the bottom left of the home screen (the "Type Here To Search" next to the Cortana button in Windows 10).

Instead of searching from there, after following the instructions given in the top answer, search in the actual file explorer, as shown here:

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/search-through-file-contents-windows-10/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Users (That is a selection above and that definitely includes your Desktop. Also see if you can add Outlook as a selection (you should be able to). That will index everything you normally need, certainly your desktop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see you found your solution. You can determine the file system location of your **Desktop** folder (most likely under **OneDrive**) by viewing the **Location** tab in the folder's **Properties** dialog:
[image]

I also wanted to share a search tip. I, too, keep a lot of files & folders on my **Desktop**. I add the Desktop folder to the **Documents *Library***, giving my one-stop searching of my **Documents** & **Desktop** folders:
[image]
[image]